# Find combinations of this set that verify condition

Tags: expression-manipulation, inequalities

So I have the following expression:

```
expr = 3 Sqrt[87.3047 (TolC2)^2 + 55.3027 (TolL1)^2 + 
  3.19092 (TolL3)^2 + 1.36097 (TolRin)^2 + 1.09369 (TolRout)^2]
```

All the variables can take values from the set

```
CatalogTolerances = {0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01}
```

I want to determine all combinations of values in CatalogTolerances that satisfy

```
expr<1
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
expr = 3 Sqrt[87.3047 (TolC2)^2 + 55.3027 (TolL1)^2 + 3.19092 (TolL3)^2 + 
  1.36097 (TolRin)^2 + 1.09369 (TolRout)^2];
CatalogTolerances = {0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01};
list=Tuples[CatalogTolerances,5]; (*all possible tolerance combinations*)
f[v_]:=Map[Apply[Rule,#]&,Transpose[{{TolC2,TolL1,TolL3,TolRin,TolRout},v}]];
rules=Map[f,list]; (*all possible tolerance combinations as rules*)
results=Map[{#,expr/.#}&,rules]; (*find all expr given tolerances*)
Select[results,#[[2]]<1&] (*select expr that are <1 given tolerances*)
```

And that shows you the 1037 expr that are < 1 given a tolerance combination

Comment: Thank you for your comment! This works just fine: I have a few more questions. If I want to select only the solutions where the sum of the tolerances is higher (or *the* solution), how can I do that? Also I want to exclude some solutions that for instance have TolL1 equal to 0.01, how can I manipulate the solutions like that? Also can I do this simultaneously with multiple inequalities? Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand your third sentence, can you explain? To exclude solutions with `TolL1==0.01` make `list` and then make it shorter with `list=DeleteCases[list,{_,0.01,_,_,_}];` To choose solutions with 1/2<expr<1 use `Select[results,1/2<#[[2]]<1&]` Study the help pages for each function I used and try to understand what I was thinking as I wrote that line. I tried to mostly do that one step at a time so you could see each line getting one step closer to your desired result. If you want to add too many more conditions then I may be better to redo this in a different way. Don't know yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your function:

```
 expr[{TolC2_, TolL1_, TolL3_, TolRin_, TolRout_}] := 
   3 Sqrt[87.3047 (TolC2)^2 + 55.3027 (TolL1)^2 + 3.19092 (TolL3)^2 + 
   1.36097 (TolRin)^2 + 1.09369 (TolRout)^2]
```

Using `If`:

```
If[expr[#] < 1, #, Nothing] & /@ Tuples[CatalogTolerances, 5]
(*1037 combinations*)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
Cases[Tuples[CatalogTolerances, 5], {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_} /; expr[{a, b, c, d, e}] < 1]
(*1037 combinations*)
```

Comment: Hello E. Chan-López. Is it possible to use this without defining the function expr? It is better for me to handle expressions.